# Ignore substring of characters between text records words when querying MongoDB databases

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB database with some special encoding:

```
[
  {
    "key": "should be matched"
  },
  {
    "key": "should [[be matched]]"
  },
  {
    "key": "also this should be matched [[please]]"
  }
]
```

I would like to ignore the double square brackets when looking for a sentence:

```
db.collection.find({ 
  key: "should be matched"
})
```

Should be modified so that returns both results. **The square brackets could be everywhere in the sentence and this is not known a priori**. I have lost many hours and I came up with this solution:

```
$where: "this.key.replace(/\[\[|\]\]/g,'').includes('should be matched')"
```

Unfortunatly, seems that `where` operator can not be used maybe for restriction and by the way is not efficient. Is there any easy fix for this problem?

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gbi5gB87xnU) here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot, but the problem is that I don't know where the square brakets are in my data. They could be everywhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$replaceAll` in and aggregation pipeline to sanitize the field(i.e. remove `[` and `]` characters and perform your `$match` afterwards.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sanitizedKey": {
        "$replaceAll": {
          "input": {
            "$replaceAll": {
              "input": "$key",
              "find": "[",
              "replacement": ""
            }
          },
          "find": "]",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sanitizedKey: "should be matched"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      sanitizedKey: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SyDpk_nf0-I) for your reference.

Comment: Wow, impressive! Usually, I wait a couple of day before accepting, but this seems really the best solution soo far. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually a really sophisicated regex like `\[*\]*should\[*\]*\s\[*\]*be\[*\]* \[*\]*matched\[*\]*` could have been worked for your case if it can catch all possibilities of the square brackets. However, from my personal experience, I found that complex regex will be hard to understand and be maintained for my teammates. So I prefer this a bit tedious yet simpler aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Yes I also tested that solution but the problem is that text to be found come from an input text, so I would have to split every letter.